# Обращение к элементу списка (вложенному в словарь) не зная индекс

Tags: python, python-3.x, списки, словари

Приветствую. Имеется словарь:

```
example = {"count":"5","list":[
    {"Name":"name1","Surname":"surname1","Age":"age1"}, 
    {"Name":"name2","Surname":"surname2","Age":"age2"}, 
    {"Name":"name3","Surname":"surname3","Age":"age3"},
    {"Name":"name4","Surname":"surname4","Age":"age4"},
    {"Name":"name5","Surname":"surname5","Age":"age5"}
]}
```

Нужно получить значение в одном из вложенных в список словарей. По индексу все просто:

```
example = {"count":"5","list":[
    {"Name":"name1","Surname":"surname1","Age":"age1"}, 
    {"Name":"name2","Surname":"surname2","Age":"age2"}, 
    {"Name":"name3","Surname":"surname3","Age":"age3"},
    {"Name":"name4","Surname":"surname4","Age":"age4"},
    {"Name":"name5","Surname":"surname5","Age":"age5"}
]}

result = example["list"][4]["Age"]
print (result)

# Результат: age5
```

Но как быть, если индекс списка заранее неизвестен (может меняться), но есть только известная пара `"Surname":"surname5"`, которая не меняется? Т.е. чтобы искомый словарь можно было найти по "surname5" вне зависимости от того, под каким индексом он может оказаться и получить значение из "Age".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы найти в списке `example['list']` словарь, содержащий `'Surname'` ключ со значением `'surname5'` и достать из этого словаря значение `'Age'` ключа  в Питоне:

```
result = next(d['Age'] for d in example['list'] if d.get('Surname') == 'surname5')
```

В командной строчке, можно `jq` использовать:

```
$ jq -r '.list[] | select(.Surname=="surname5") | .Age' input.json
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def func():
    for dictionary in example["list"]:
        if "Surname" in dictionary and dictionary["Surname"] == "surname5":
            return dictionary

# assert func()["Age"] == "age5"
```

Comment: Видимо я чего-то не понимаю. "Инструкция assert позволяет производить проверки истинности утверждений, что может быть использовано в отладочных целях." В данном случае, значение ключа "Age" заранее неизвестно. Задача стоит в том, чтобы либо получить индекс словаря в списке (в примере это индекс 4) и обратиться к его элементу (result = example["list"][4]["Age"]), либо как-то сделать это минуя получение индекса.

Comment: В условии: [...чтобы искомый словарь можно было найти по "surname5" вне зависимости от того,...]. Словарь найден.       [assert func()["Age"] == "age5"] - это проверка, как и в условии задачи: `result = example["list"][4]["Age"]
print (result)

# Результат: age5`